# Nested site collections in SharePoint Online (O365)

Tags: sharepoint, office365

Is it possible to create nested site collections in SharePoint Online - such as  with the following URL:
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/siteCollection1/siteCollection2/siteCollection3
If yes, can please someone give instruction of how it can be done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible to create a sub site in existing site collection/subsite:

1. Enter the site collection where you are willing to create a sub-site: https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite
2. Go to "Site contents"
3. click on New:

[image]

Click on subsite.